# Conditional inclusion/execution of Makefile commands in a variable?

Tags: makefile

There is a Makefile that I am using, which I got from somewhere, and which is quite big. I have also found some things that I'd like changed occasionally in the makefile - and the easiest way to do that for me is to define (or not) a (switch) variable (say, `OVWRCHOICE`) at the start of the makefile; and then later on in the makefile code, do something like:

```
ifdef OVWRCHOICE
  MYOPT = override
  ....
endif
```

... which is all dandy and fine.

The thing is, eventually I also need to change parts in the "override" part as well, so I'd like to have it at the start of the file. So, as this "override" part contains several `make` commands -- I tried to use `define`, to have a variable which will contain the commands (which would be executed at the `ifdef OVWRCHOICE...` part).

So I arrived at this simple example:

```
# uncomment as needed;
OVWRCHOICE = YES

define SET_OVWRCHOICE
  MYOPT = override
endef
export SET_OVWRCHOICE

# ... many lines of code ...

MYOPT = default

# ... many lines of code...

# without indent:  Makefile:18: *** missing separator.  Stop.
# with tab indent: Makefile:18: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
ifdef OVWRCHOICE
    $(SET_OVWRCHOICE)
endif

all:
    @echo $(MYOPT)
```

... which fails with the errors noted. Of course, if I use the first snippet in the post instead, all runs fine, and `make` prints out the expected result: "override".

How would I go about in achieving something like this? Not sure if "inclusion" or "execution" of "Makefile commands" are even the right terms in this context; so I have a hard time in finding a starting point for a search :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it - it is described in [Eval Function - GNU `make'](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function); the right construct is:

```
ifdef OVWRCHOICE
$(eval $(call SET_OVWRCHOICE))
endif
```

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, didn't really know where to archive this snippet, so back to this old question of mine :) this is off topic for OP; but here goes:

To test how environment variables are processed by a makefile, here is a simple example:

```
Foo=something
all :
ifdef DEBUG
    @echo "Debug defined"
else
    @echo "Debug NOT defined"
endif
```

... and here is the test for it:

```
$ make
Debug NOT defined
$ make DEBUG
make: *** No rule to make target `DEBUG'.  Stop.
$ DEBUG make
DEBUG: command not found
$ DEBUG= make
Debug NOT defined
$ DEBUG=1 make
Debug defined
```

... so obviously, the right syntax to set that variable inside the makefile from the command line is: "`DEBUG=1 make`"